# "A Java Exception has occurred"

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

So I'm trying to run my pacman project as a jar(also tried runnable) and I just get the error message you see in the title. It runs perfectly fine in eclipse/netbeans, but whilst cleaning/building i see the warnings:
Note: C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Eclipse\PackMan\src\game\packman\GameData.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

The main class is correct and assigned. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?
Here is my GameData class

```
public class GameData {

int mazeNo;
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Position> pills;
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Position> powerPills;
public MoverInfo packman;
public GhostInfo[] ghostInfos = new GhostInfo[4];
public int score;

Maze[] mazes;
boolean dead = false;
boolean win = false;

public GameData() {
    mazes = new Maze[4];
    // load mazes information
    for (int m=0; m<4; m++) {
        mazes[m] = new Maze(m);
    }
    setMaze(mazeNo);
}

private void setMaze(int m) {
    packman = new MoverInfo(mazes[m].packmanPos);
    for (int g=0; g<4; g++) {
        ghostInfos[g] = new GhostInfo(mazes[m].ghostPos);
    }
    pills = new CopyOnWriteArrayList((List<Position>)(mazes[m].pills.clone()));
    powerPills = new CopyOnWriteArrayList((List<Position>)(mazes[m].powerPills.clone()));
}

public void movePackMan(int reqDir) {
    if (move(reqDir, packman)) {
        packman.curDir = reqDir;
    } else {
        move(packman.curDir, packman);
    }

}



private int wrap(int value, int incre, int max) {
    return (value+max+incre)%max;
}

private boolean move(int reqDir, MoverInfo info) {
    // current position of packman is (row, column)
    int row = info.pos.row;
    int column = info.pos.column;
    int rows = mazes[mazeNo].rows;
    int columns = mazes[mazeNo].columns;
    int nrow = wrap(row, MoverInfo.DROW[reqDir], rows);
    int ncol = wrap(column, MoverInfo.DCOL[reqDir], columns);
    if (mazes[mazeNo].charAt(nrow, ncol) != '0') {
        info.pos.row = nrow;
        info.pos.column = ncol;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public void update() {
    if (pills.contains(packman.pos)) {
        pills.remove(packman.pos);
        score += 5;
    } else if (powerPills.contains(packman.pos)) {
        powerPills.remove(packman.pos);
        score += 50;
        for (GhostInfo g:ghostInfos) {
            g.edibleCountDown = 500;
        }
    }
    for (GhostInfo g:ghostInfos) {
        if (g.edibleCountDown > 0) {
            if (touching(g.pos, packman.pos)) {
                // eat the ghost and reset
                score += 100;
                g.curDir = g.reqDir = MoverInfo.LEFT;
                g.pos.row = mazes[mazeNo].ghostPos.row;
                g.pos.column = mazes[mazeNo].ghostPos.column;
                g.edibleCountDown = 0;
            }
            g.edibleCountDown--;
        } else {
            if (touching(g.pos, packman.pos)) {
                dead = true;
            }
        }
    }
    // level is cleared
    if (pills.isEmpty() && powerPills.isEmpty()) {
        mazeNo++;
        if (mazeNo < 4) {
            setMaze(mazeNo);
        } else if (mazeNo == 5) {
            win = true;
        } else {
            // game over
            dead = true;
        }
    }
}
private boolean touching(Position a, Position b) {
    return Math.abs(a.row-b.row) + Math.abs(a.column-b.column) < 3;
}

public void moveGhosts(int[] reqDirs) {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        GhostInfo info = ghostInfos[i];
        info.reqDir = reqDirs[i];
        if (move(info.reqDir, info)) {
            info.curDir = info.reqDir;
        } else {
            move(info.curDir, info);
        }
    }
}
public int getWidth() {
    return mazes[mazeNo].width;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return mazes[mazeNo].height;
}

public List<Integer> getPossibleDirs(Position pos) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int d=0; d<4;d++) {
        Position npos = getNextPositionInDir(pos, d);
        if (mazes[mazeNo].charAt(npos.row, npos.column) != '0') {
            list.add(d);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

private Position getNextPositionInDir(Position pos, int d) {
    int nrow = wrap(pos.row, MoverInfo.DROW[d], mazes[mazeNo].rows);
    int ncol = wrap(pos.column, MoverInfo.DCOL[d], mazes[mazeNo].columns);
    return new Position(nrow, ncol);
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide more error logs.

Comment: How do you run the jar file? What happens when you run `java -jar yourJarFile.jar` in a command prompt?

Comment: Don't you see a stack trace?  If yes post it here and tell us what on the source code line.

Comment: "So I'm trying to run my pacman project as a jar" - You need to include that in your question then.

Comment: when i try the command JB suggested I get "no main manifest attribute," however in the manifest it DOES say what the main class is

Comment: Post the manifest for us to see.